# Review audit fail when trying to edit a post

Tags: support, review-audits

I was [reviewing this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/19680443) on the late answers queue, and got a message that I failed the review audit, and can't really understand why.

The action I was taking was editing - I planned on make it a bit more readable (inline those links under the document title), and than leave a comment about how to improve this answer (not only linking, but quoting).

Was I acting wrong about that?
Should I first leave a comment and only then vote/edit? Anything else?

Thanks!

---

The question: [Couchbase 5.0 with Spring-boot XML configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48638438/2350423)

Attaching a screenshot since I don't know if the review link is available for everyone and for always:

[image]

Comment: Even if you edit this, it isn't a good answer. It's a link only answer, edited or not. Your edit would not have made the answer good....

Comment: @Patrice What if the edit is to include the information from the link in the answer? Thus making it not a link-only answer anymore.

Comment: I planned on a minimal edit, to make it more readable, and leaving a comment for the user to ask him to add quotes - so he would also know how to improve it, and will be better for the next time

Comment: @AndréKool oh I get that here. However this wasn't the edit that arieljannay planned here (I understand the difference, yes).  This is one of those less than optimal audits. However the actions that were about to be taken on the post warrant that response from the audit system IMHO. (now, someone who would come in and edit all the info from the links into this would get the same reception, and I agree **that** is a problem)

Comment: The post was deleted a week ago.  What exactly did you edit?

Comment: @HansPassant Nothing eventually. I wanted to edit and I failed the audit for that. A week ago? Wow, so why did I get it in the review queue? :O

Comment: Audits were designed to check that reviewers pay attention.  They tried to make it easy, like picking a post that was deleted by an earlier review.  Not noticing that it is gone gives you the "stop, look" message.

Comment: I'm not sure there was a sign that this post was deleted, that I can remember. I guess if I would've open the post I could see it - but I planned on acting on it from the review page. Do you have an example to that message ("stop, look")? I just remember getting the failed message and that it was a test.

Comment: @arieljannai getting failed message says "stop, look....". This was a test, so it does not matter if post is deleted. It is probable that test questions are deleted or closed.